# SuiteFlow||SuiteScript: Send email based on file size

Tags: netsuite

We have a Suiteflow that sends an email as an attachment. However, the email doesn't send if the attachment is over 5 MB in size. I want to add a condition to the action that says when document size is < 5 MB. I planned on then adding a separate action to send the email without the attachment if the file size is >= 5 MB. Is this possible and if not, what work around is there?

SuiteScript (Javascript) is certainly an option but I would prefer just modifying the existing SuiteFlow

::In Response to below comments:
The email attachment is added to a Document field on the Transaction, not in the File subtab. I cannot find how to get at it's properties (like size) therefore in a search. (idea #2 below). 
Also, the code sample (idea #1) does not work because nlapiLoadFile will not load a file > 5 mb, meaning I can't do a test etc. I am trying to avoid writing the whole thing as a script.

So far the only solution (and I don't feel it is a good one) is to take the sending of the email, make it into a script, and do a try catch on it. Any other ideas??

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the file that you are sending as an attachment is a file that already exists in Netsuite file cabinet you can add a script to validate the size of the attachment:

```
var load = nlapiLoadFile('100');//where 100 is the internal id of the file
var filesize = load.getSize(); //Returns the size of the file in bytes

if(filesize > .....) //
```

For reference of using this Suitescript API:

Helpguide > SuiteCloud (Customization, Scripting, and Web Services) : SuiteScript : SuiteScript API : SuiteScript Objects : nlobjFile

Comment: I guess I am confused. In the documentation (https://netsuite.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/10265/kw/nlobjfile) it says "In SuiteScript there is a 5MB limitation to the size of the file/document that can be created, submitted, or accessed using file APIs such as nlapiLoadFile, nlapiPrintRecord, nlapiMergeRecord, nlapiXMLToPDF, nlapiSubmitFile, and nlapiCreateFile."

Wouldn't this mean that I can't load a file if part of my concern is that exceeds the 5 MB limit?

Comment: Problem solved then. If you can't load that file then that means it doesn't qualify to your limit.

Comment: So what... turn my whole workflow into a SuiteScript and then do a try catch on trying to load the file? I would love to do what you are saying where I actually condition on the size, but you can't get the size if it breaks.

Answer (score 0):

I konw its not efficient but how about doing a search to get the size of the file. Something like this

Filters:
Internal Id = internal id of the attachment

Results:
Size

The Size column would return the file size in KB.

Comment: Actually, this might just work. Workflow conditions on searches generally don't take too long and I may be able to use date ranges to ensure the list never grows too big. Great idea! I will try this and see if it works